# Can I bind a Launchpad shortcut on my [PC] mouse?

Tags: macos, launchpad

I have created a shortcut for Launchpad using the keyboard, but cannot figure out how to make one for the 4th button on my mouse. This would eliminate the need for even using the dock...for the most part.

Comment: What kind of mouse are you using? Does it come with its own Preferences pane or setup application (Logitech models usually do for instance)?

Comment: It's an off brand from Office Max :) no software for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net):

[image]